# Joomla 3 Вопрос о нагрузке на сервер

Tags: joomla, php, cms, hosting, mysql

Добрый вечер. Вот такая ситуация сложилась,что, мне не рекомендуют и даже запрещают использовать Joomla 3.2 для создании сайта (хостинг не мой вот и указывают).Твердят так:

> Joomla 3 Загружает сервер больше чем
> Joomla 2.5, по этому, только Joomla
> 2.5

Правда ли это, о большей нагрузке?

Comment: Не так страшна джумла , как криво написанные доп. модули. 
А насчёт версий 3 и 2 Вам правильно сказали. 3 версия больше ресурсов кушает. Больше функционала, больше ресурсов требуется.

Comment: Функционал это - да, но если я не в админ панели, тогда одинакова при просмотре сайта нагрузка?